# Conditional Distribution of The Sum of Two Standard Normal Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a question about conditional Distribution. Let $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ and independently distributed. Then, let $Z=X+Y$. 
Find the p.d.f and c.d.f of $Z\mid(X>0, Y>0)$.

The hint here is to use the circular symmetry of joint density of $X$ and $Y$. No integration needed.

My attempt:

First, we know that $Z\sim N(0,2)$ then the p.d.f of $Z$ is $f_{Z}(z)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{\frac{-z^{2}}{4}},-\infty<z<\infty.$

Next, we have that:

$$F_{Z\mid X>0,Y>0}(z\mid x>0,y>0)=P(Z\leq z\mid X>0,Y>0)=\frac{P(Z\leq z, X>0,Y>0)}{P(X>0,Y>0)}.$$

It follows that by independence:

\begin{align}
& F_{Z\mid X>0,Y>0}(z\mid x>0,y>0) = \frac{P(0<Z\leq z)}{P(X>0)P(Y>0)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{F_Z(z)-F_Z(0)}{\frac{1}{4}} = 4F_Z(z)-\frac{4}{2}=4F_Z(z)-2.
\end{align}

So, the c.d.f is: $F_{Z\mid X>0,Y>0}(z\mid x>0,y>0)=4F_Z(z)-2$.

Then, the p.d.f will be $$f_{Z\mid X>0,Y>0}(z\mid x,y)=4f_Z(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{\frac{-z^{2}}{4}},0<z<\infty.$$

This is what I got; however, I'm pretty sure I did something wrong since when I integrate the p.d.f over the whole region, it does not give me 1.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The independence of $X$ and $Y$ doesn't imply $P(Z \leqslant z \mid X > 0, Y > 0) = P(0 < Z \leqslant z)$.

Comment: That's what I thought as well; however, I did not know what would it be. I think it should be  $P(0<X\leq z-Y,0<Y\leq z)$. But I don't know how to work around this probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the phrase "using the circular symmetry of the joint density of $(X,Y)$" most likely refers to the polar decomposition$$(X,Y)=^d(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$$ where $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent, $\Theta$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$, and the PDF of $R$ is $re^{-r^2/2}$ on $r>0$.

Thus, one is after the conditional distribution of $Z=R(\cos\Theta+\sin\Theta)$ conditionally on $\Theta\in(0,\frac\pi2)$.

Equivalently, thanks to the identity $\cos\Theta+\sin\Theta=\sqrt2\cos(\Theta-\frac\pi4)$, this is also the unconditional distribution of $$W=\sqrt2R\cos\Phi$$ where $\Phi$ is independent of $R$ and uniform on $(-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi4)$, or uniform on $(0,\frac\pi4)$.

Can you continue?

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me try to work it out. Thanks!